# How can i create account for a program with max 10MB size in solana

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

I know that initially, while creating we can use upto 10240 bytes

Later, from solana cookbook docs i got know we can increase the size of account
But,if i want increase the account size upto 10MB how can i do that

https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#facts
https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-change-account-size

can anyone pls let me know the achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The 10KiB limit for accounts is only for accounts on program-derived addresses.  For addresses with a keypair, you can allocate 10MB.  Here's some rough pseudocode:

```
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_sdk::commitment_config::CommitmentLevel;
use solana_sdk::transaction::Transaction;
use solana_sdk::system_instruction;

let payer = Keypair::new();
let account = Keypair::new();
let rpc_client = RpcClient::new_with_commitment("...", CommitmentLevel::Confirmed);
let space = 10_000_000;
let lamports = ...; // figure this out with rent

let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[system_instruction::create_account(&payer.pubkey(), &account.pubkey(), space, lamports)],
    Some(&payer.pubkey()),
    [payer, account],
    recent_blockhash
);

rpc_client.send_transaction(transaction);
```

Alternatively, you can do multiple `realloc` calls inside your program to give it an additional 10KiB on every call.